# My javascript doesn't run without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with a block of my code, this section creates boxes of chocolates based on what a user chooses in a previous step and what data is pulled from the database in the api script.
the problem is that it doesn't work without the alert('hi') in it. if i take that out it will just create an empty box without dropping the flavors in it, the flavor the flavors are inserted with the createFlavorArray function.

```
var product = new Array();
var price = new Array();
var size = new Array();

$(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'phpscripts/api.php',      
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',    
          success: function(rows)        
        {
        count = 0;
          for (var i in rows)
          {
            var row = rows[i];          
              product[count] = row[0];
              price[count] = row[1];
              size[count] = row[2];
              count++;
          }
        } 
      });
    });

//b = box
//o = option that is inside the box
//nextBoxId is the box id
//nextFlavorId is the option or flavor id

var nextBoxId = 1;
var nextFlavorId = 1;
var orderCap = 0;
var subTotal = 0;
var numOfChocolates = 0;
var numOfBoxes = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

    while (halfPoundBoxes > 0) {
            $("#boxes").append('<div id="b'+nextBoxId+'"></div>');
            $('#b'+nextBoxId).addClass('div-table-selection');
            $('#b'+nextBoxId).append($('#minusBox').clone().attr('id', "m"+nextBoxId));
            $('#b'+nextBoxId).append('<div style="display:table-row"></div>');

            //call the function to loop through and create the number of flavor options needed
            var x = 0;
            alert('hi');
            while(x < product.length){
                if ('1/2lb Box' == product[x]) {
                    createFlavorArray(size[x], nextBoxId);
                    subTotal += price[x] * 1;
                    $('#b'+nextBoxId).attr('title', product[x]);
                }
                x++;

            }
            //clone the delete box button and make it visible

            $('#m'+nextBoxId).show(500);
            $('#b'+nextBoxId).append("<br />");

            if (orderCap == 0) {
            $('#boxes').append('<div id="msg"><p>If you wish to add another box to your order select the size and click +1 Box.</p></div>');
            }

            $("#m"+nextBoxId).click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                orderCap--;
                //if they're ordering zero boxes hide the order button
                //remove total price
                //remove the message
                if (orderCap == 0)
                {
                    document.getElementById('orderBtn').style.display = "none";
                    $("#msg").remove();
                    $("#totalPrice").empty();
                }
                if (orderCap < 10)
                {
                    $("#cap").remove();
                    $("#addBox").show(500);
                }
                var y = 0;
                while (y < product.length) {
                    if ('1/2lb Box' == product[y]) {
                    subTotal -= price[y] * 1;
                    numOfChocolates -= size[y] * 1;
                    }
                    y++;
                }
                $('#totalPrice').html("<p>Sub Total: " + subTotal + "</p>")
                //subtract the new
                $('#finalpaypal').val(subTotal);

            });
            nextBoxId++;
            orderCap++;
            numOfBoxes++;
            $('#totalPrice').html("<p>Sub Total: " + subTotal + "</p>")
            halfPoundBoxes--;   
    }
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, so the code runs before the call is done.  The `alert` delays the code, and when you close it, it just so happens that the AJAX call is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the code in a function and run it after the ajax success is finished

```
...
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'phpscripts/api.php',      
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',    
      success: function(rows)        
    {
    count = 0;
      for (var i in rows)
      {
        var row = rows[i];          
          product[count] = row[0];
          price[count] = row[1];
          size[count] = row[2];
          count++;
      }
      do_after_ajax();
    } 
  });
});

function do_after_ajax(){
        while (halfPoundBoxes > 0) {
        $("#boxes").append('<div id="b'+nextBoxId+'"></div>');
        $('#b'+nextBoxId).addClass('div-table-selection');
        ....
}
```

Comment: It seems like it never calls the function when i change it to that.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your code is working only when using an `alert()`, is that the `alert()` action is giving your jQuery AJAX request a few seconds to return a value to your `success()` call back function.

You should move any code which is affected by your callout function, into the callout function also, so that this code runs in the correct order.

---

Alternatively you could not run your AJAX request asynchronosly by adding `async:false`, but as [@Rocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976253/my-javascript-doesnt-run-without-alert#comment15965381_11976295) has commented, this isn't recommended.

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
```

Comment: I ***highly*** suggest **not** using `async:false`.  It **will** lock up the browser and make it unresponsive until the AJAX call is done.  You should use callbacks instead.

Comment: @Rocket Thanks for your comment, I hadn't considered `async:false` could cause bad repercussions. Cheers for the info.

Comment: Well, changing it to async:false does indeed make it work and it does lockup but only for a second. So i will move the create box code into the success function of the api ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to operate on markup returned by your ajax. That code needs to be moved into the success callback of the ajax request. The reason the alert call makes it work is simply that it delays everything else long enough for the page to finish loading.